# Как изменить массив а функции kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Я хорошо знаком с языком c++, а сейчас решил выучить kotlin, но у меня возник вопрос по поводу функций и передаваемых в них значений. Как я понял, переменные передаются только по значению. Как в таком случае я могу менять объект внутри функции? Возможно ли сделать функцию ввода элементов массива, чтобы в последуюдем с ним работать?

Comment: Как раз наоборот - все передается по ссылке. При изменении значения внутри массива или переданного объекта внутри функции эти изменения будут "видны" в объекте снаружи функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Вот пример:

```
fun fillArray(arrayToFill: Array<Int>) {
    arrayToFill[0] = 1
    arrayToFill[1] = 2
}

fun test() {
    val arrayToFill = Array<Int>(2)
    fillArray(arrayToFill)
    println(arrayToFill) //выведет [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: Почему тут не будет передачи по значению?

Comment: Вроде как передастся по значению ссылка на массив

Comment: В таком случае, возможна ли передача массива так, чтобы в теле функции мы работали с копией, а не с экземпляром?

Comment: Средствами языка - такого не сделать. Если надо - создавайте в методе копию массива и работайте с ним.